# Cordova iPhone X status bar adds white empty bar

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar, iphone-x

I want to use `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` set to `false` on all ios devices, but then I get a white bar on iPhone X

[image: Cordova iPhone X]

If I set `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` to `true` then there's no white bar on iPhone X but all other phones without a "notch" will get undesired overlaid status bar which I will have to account for with css, that I don't want to do.

[image]

Is there a way for statusbar plugin to not add that extra white space on iPhone X ?

For the record I have latest statusbar plugin installed from github and `viewport-fit=cover` set

Comment: Can you post your config.xml ? Im facing the same problem and cannot solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin doesn't work well if you don't use it in the full screen app.

Switch to using launch storyboards (see splash screen plugin docs), and you will have the full screen app on iPhone X and the statusbar plugin will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you both, indeed using storyboard solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using the latest `cordova-plugin-statusbar` and `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`. And you MUST use Launch storyboard images for the layout to work properly.